# Stop recyclerview from trying to update when "Favourite" button is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-room

I have a "favourite" button for each row of my recyclerview which the user clicks when the like the image (obviously). Each row is a cardview that I only want to "flip" when the user opens the fragment.

When the user clicks the button I update my database with "Y" or "N".
My problem is that my recyclerview refreshes even though the list hasn't changed. When it refreshes all my cards flip which I do not want. How can I stop the recyclerview from updating when the button is clicked?

Here is my adapter class

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NotNull final ClothesViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        String image;

        if (flip) {
                holder.flipView.flipTheView();
            }
            ClothingItem current = mClothingItems.get(position);
            holder.itemNameView.setText(current.getItem());
            holder.categoryNameView.setText(current.getCategory());
            holder.seasonNameView.setText(current.getSeason());

            Integer yesCount = current.getYesCount();
            Integer noCount = current.getNoCount();


            if (current.getFavourite().equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                holder.animationView.setProgress(0);
            }
            else {
                holder.animationView.setProgress(1);
            }

            holder.yesTextView.setText(String.valueOf(yesCount));
            holder.noTextView.setText(String.valueOf(noCount));
            image = current.getPhotoPath();
            Glide.with(holder.cardView)
                    .load(image)
                    .into(holder.pictureView);

            flip = false;

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e("Picture","onBindViweHolder: Null Point:" + e.getMessage());
        }

        holder.animationView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                listener.onFavouriteClick(position);


            }
        });

 public interface clickButtons {

        void onFavouriteClick(int position);

    }
```

Fragment Class

```
 @Override
    public void onFavouriteClick(int position) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
        LottieAnimationView animationView = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.favouriteAnimation);

        ClothingItem item = springList.get(position);
        final Long id = item.getId();

        if (animationView.getProgress() > 0) {

            animationView.setProgress(0);
            mClothingViewModel.updateFavourite(id.intValue(), "N");
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(position,"favourite");

       } else if (animationView.getProgress() == 0) {

            animationView.playAnimation();
         
            mClothingViewModel.updateFavourite(id.intValue(),"Y");

        }
    }
```

I tried to use onBindViewHolder with payloads but I get the same result. I think I'm not calling this properly

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(position,"favourite");
```

Adapter class

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ClothesViewHolder holder ,final int position, final List<Object> payloads){
        String image;

        if(!payloads.isEmpty()) {
            ClothingItem current = mClothingItems.get(position);
            holder.itemNameView.setText(current.getItem());
            holder.categoryNameView.setText(current.getCategory());
            holder.seasonNameView.setText(current.getSeason());

            Integer yesCount = current.getYesCount();
            Integer noCount = current.getNoCount();

            if(yesCount == null) {

                yesCount = 0;
            }
            if (noCount == null) {

                noCount = 0;
            }

            if (current.getFavourite() == null || current.getFavourite().equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                holder.animationView.setProgress(0);
            }
            else {
                holder.animationView.setProgress(1);
            }

//            Log.d("Counting","Yes count " + yesCount + " no count " + noCount);

            holder.yesTextView.setText(String.valueOf(yesCount));
            holder.noTextView.setText(String.valueOf(noCount));
            image = current.getPhotoPath();
            Glide.with(holder.cardView)
                    .load(image)
                    .into(holder.pictureView);

        } else {

            onBindViewHolder(holder,position);
        }
    }
```

Fragment

```
 @Override
    public void onFavouriteClick(int position) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
        LottieAnimationView animationView = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.favouriteAnimation);

        ClothingItem item = springList.get(position);
        final Long id = item.getId();

        if (animationView.getProgress() > 0) {

            animationView.setProgress(0);
            mClothingViewModel.updateFavourite(id.intValue(), "N");
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(position,"favourite");

       } else if (animationView.getProgress() == 0) {

            animationView.playAnimation();

            mClothingViewModel.updateFavourite(id.intValue(),"Y");
              
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(position,"favourite");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview is updated or refreshed when notifiydataSetChanged is called.
try to remove notifiyDataSetChanged in the click event maybe

Comment: Hi Rommy, I removed that but the recyclerview keeps refreshing